# Best way to add two collections in .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, list

Hi I have 2 Lists Say xmlNodeList1 , xmlNodeList2

What is the best way to create xmlNodeList3 which contains all the nodes of  xmlNodeList1 & xmlNodeList2

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx)

```
var xmlNodeList3 = xmlNodeList1.Concat(xmlNodeList2);
```

Comment: Note: xmNodeList3 is not a list, so it doesn't actually contain any items. It just reads items from the other lists.

Comment: Yes, you can do var xmlNodeList3 = xmlNodeList1.Concat(xmlNodeList2).ToList();

Answer (score 5):

Create a new list with the capacity to hold all items, and then add all the items to it. Example:

```
List<string> list3 = new List<string>(list1.Count + list2.Count);
list3.AddRange(list1);
list3.AddRange(list2);
```

By setting the capacity, the list doesn't have to do any memory allocations while you copy the items to it.